# Все посты изчезают из админки кроме последнего

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Делаю свой первый php проект.

Нужно с все комментарии к определонному посту показать.То есть с права от картинки поста есть 2 блока один красный не потвержденные комментарии и зеленый потвержденные комментарии.

В курсе (котором используетсья старый `php`) парень добавляет этот код у него все работает замечательно правда погуглив я все же не понял почему у него это работает ведь `array_shift` **извлекает только первый элемент** массива.

Короче после добавления этого кода для того чтобы показать сколько есть комментарии у каждого поста у меня все посты исчезли кроме последней.Но комментарии работают.Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот данный код если убрать все посты будут видны.(Но комментарии не будут работать)

```
    <td> 
<!-- status on -->
    <?php
        $connection; //покдлючение к базе данным
        $queryApproved = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments  WHERE admin_panel_id='$id' AND status='ON'"; //берем коммент с БД у которого таблица статус равно ON
        $execute = mysqli_query($connection,$queryApproved); //выполняем
        $rows_approved = mysqli_fetch_array($execute); 
        $total_approved = array_shift($rows_approved);//извлекает первый элемент если документация не врет
        if($total_approved > 0){    //если потвержденные комментарии больше нулья       
    ?>
    <span class="badge float-right badge-success"><?php  echo $total_approved; ?></span> //показать их

    <?php } ?>
    <!-- status off -->
        <?php

//тоже самый код как и наверху только тут берет  если статус равен OFF то есть не потвержден админом
        $connection;
        
        $queryUnApproved = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments  WHERE admin_panel_id='$id' AND status='OFF'";
        $execute = mysqli_query($connection,$queryUnApproved);
        $rows_un_approved = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
        $total_un_approved = array_shift($rows_un_approved);
        if($total_un_approved > 0){          
    ?>
    <span class="badge float-left badge-danger"><?php  echo $total_un_approved; ?></span>

    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Для полной ясности загружу картинку

> До добавления кода все посты на месте все работает

[image]

> После добавления кода как видите все посты изчезли но комментарии
> работают .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переименуйте все переменные кроме `$connection` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: А ещё лучше сделать функцию, которая будет принимать флаг `status`, на основе которой будет делаться выборка

Comment: O.o но как ?скажите прошу вас как вы догадались что у меня ошибка в переменных?Где была ошибка?И еще разве array_shift не извлекает первый элемент ?Спасибо огромное заранее вы мне очень помогли плюсик дал.

Comment: скажите плз откуда же узнали

Comment: @Demon__ANT просто догадался -.- практика была ;)

Comment: ладно не говорите =(

Comment: @Demon__ANT яж вам ответил, просто догадался. метод дедукции как у Шерлока

Comment: @Manitikyl O_o  понял спс :)